# IOS - Pause and Unpause Currently Playing Music

Tags: ios, playback, ipod, playing

I am working on a IOS app that I want to have the functionality to pause and unpause music that is currently playing through the ipod, just like the ipod's play/pause button. Is there anyway to do that through IOS? The only answers I have found for this is for dealing with songs and sounds played locally through the app.

Any help would be fantastic. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] play];
[[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] pause];
```

Comment: These methods aren't obvious in the MPMusicPlayerController docs because they're defined in the MPMediaPlayback protocol this class conforms to.

Comment: as of iOS8 use `systemMusicPlayer` instead of `iPodMusicPlayer`