# How to implement avrcp features (play, pause, prev, next) in bluetooth app

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, avrcp

I am creating a bluetooth app, where I need to give the player controls in my app. 
First the iPhone is connected to bluetooth speaker and plays songs via phone music player app.
Now if I open my app, I need to play, pause, prev, next that song.

I read about core bluetooth framework, CBservices and CBcharacteristics but I don't know what uuid should I specify for these services and characteristics.

Reference: https://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor
In this tutorial the services they get from https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services

I need the uuids for play, pause etc features.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have tagged both objective-C and Swift. which one are you looking for. also i would recommend the iOS tag to make it easier for people to find your question

Comment: If the music player is on your device then you don't need to use Bluetooth; you need to control the music player; the fact that audio output is routed to a Bluetooth speaker is immaterial.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043365/ios-pause-and-unpause-currently-playing-music